# Spinner dropdown border bottom remove

Tags: android, border, spinner, dropdown

**Default**

[image: Default]

**Popup**

[image: Popup]

**Hello, as seen in the picture, a border line appears under the default object. How can I prevent it.**

https://github.com/codingdemos/SpinnerImages/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/codingdemos/spinnerimages/CustomAdapter.java

I used the sample code found here, everything is perfect, but I am waiting for your help with the line boundary breaker in the normal view, thank you

activity_main.xml

```
 <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/lesson_spinner"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/mainSelectBoxArrowBg"
            android:popupTheme="@color/spinnerColorBg"
            android:spinnerMode="dialog" />
```

spinner_list_style.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:background="@drawable/spinner_bg_style"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/flagName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/ivFlag"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ivFlag"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:foregroundGravity="center_vertical"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="@color/spinnerColorText"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

spinner_bg_style.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#ffffff"/>
            <stroke android:color="#E6E6E6" android:width="1dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:bottom="2dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#ffffff"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
    view.setBackgroundResource(0); //fix
}
@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

}
```

});

I found the solution :)